# how to pass column name as a parameter when groupby and apply

Tags: python, pandas, apply

In python pandas, when do `df.groupby('columnA').apply(myfunction)`, how to pass columnA into the function? The values in columnA will be used to do further data filtering.

Have tried below and it won't work

```
df.groupby('columnA').apply(myfunction,('columnA'))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post some sample data and a desired output? It could be easier to help you

Comment: You can still access it via the `GroupBy` object even if you group on it: `df.groupby('columnA')['columnA'].apply(myfunction)`

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can access the column you group on via `GroupBy` via

```
df.groupby('columnA')['columnA'].apply(myfunction)
```

---

**Minimal Verifiable Example**

```
def myfunc(x):
    return x.sum()

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abbac'), 'B': range(5)})
df
   A  B
0  a  0
1  b  1
2  b  2
3  a  3
4  c  4

df.groupby('A')['A'].apply(myfunc)    
A
a    aa
b    bb
c     c
Name: A, dtype: object
```